# Erase IsolatedStorage from Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building a wp7 app. I am using IsolatedStorage. Sometimes, for testing purposes, I'd like to erase everything my app has put into IsolatedStorage. Is there a way to do this for the emulator, or must I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll lose all isolated storage for all apps by restarting the emulator.

Alternatively, you could uninstall the app from the emulator via tap and hold on the app list.

Comment: I don't see this behaviour. When running on the emu, isolated storage is destroyed upon each debugging session.

Comment: Oh hang on, now it does. Seems unreliable. Odd. Readers should expect 'oddness'.

Answer (score 6):

If you did want to do this programatically the code is very simple:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    store.Remove();
}
```